# Get-NetConnectionProfile Integration Question

Tags: powershell, nic

Good afternoon folks. I need some assistance.

I've got a PS Script that creates a nice elaborate report for the Machine ran on. I am having an issue integrating Get-NetConnectionProfile into my script. that returns IP addresses for each adapter on the machine.

Here is my current code:

```
    $NICCount = 0
    $colAdapters = gwmi -ComputerName $Target Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration

    "@
    Foreach ($objAdapter in $colAdapters)
    {
        if ($objAdapter.IPEnabled -eq "True")
        {
            $NICCount = $NICCount + 1
            If ($NICCount -gt 1)
            {
                $Report+=  "            </TABLE>"
                $Report+=  "                <DIV class=Solidfiller></DIV>"
                $Report+=  "            <TABLE>"
            }
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Description</b></font></th>"
THIS LINE HERE:     $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.Description)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Physical address</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.MACaddress)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        If ($objAdapter.IPAddress -ne $Null)
        {
            $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
            $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>IP Address / Subnet Mask</b></font></th>"
            $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$(gwmi -ComputerName $Target Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPEnabled -eq $true } | Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddress } | Foreach-Object { [IPAddress]$_ } | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'Internetwork' } | Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddressToString }) / $($objAdapter.IPSubnet)</font></td>"
            $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
            $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
            $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
            $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Default Gateway</b></font></th>"
            $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway)</font></td>"
            $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        
        }
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>DHCP enabled</b></font></th>"
        If ($objAdapter.DHCPEnabled -eq "True")
        {
            $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>Yes</font></td>"
        }
        Else
        {
            $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>No</font></td>"
        }
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                            <th width='25%'><b>DNS Servers</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  "                            <td width='75%'>"
        If ($objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder -ne $Null)
        {
            $Report+=  " $($objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder) "
        }
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Primary WINS Server</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.WINSPrimaryServer)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Secondary WINS Server</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.WINSSecondaryServer)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $NICCount = $NICCount + 1
        }
    }
$Report+= @"
```

What I am trying to do, is something like this that will show the actual NIC Alias that is listed in Windows as the "Connections" label, instead of the NIC just always showing vmxnet3, Wi-Fi Adapter 4, etc. for each and every adapter:

```
    $NICInformation = Get-NetConnectionProfile
    $NICCount = 0
    $colAdapters = gwmi -ComputerName $Target Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration

    "@
    Foreach ($objAdapter in $colAdapters)
    {
        if ($objAdapter.IPEnabled -eq "True")
        {
            $NICCount = $NICCount + 1
            If ($NICCount -gt 1)
            {
                $Report+=  "            </TABLE>"
                $Report+=  "                <DIV class=Solidfiller></DIV>"
                $Report+=  "            <TABLE>"
            }
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Description</b></font></th>"
THIS LINE HERE $Report+=  "                     <td width='75%'>$($NICInformation.InterfaceAlias)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Physical address</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.MACaddress)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        If ($objAdapter.IPAddress -ne $Null)
        {
            $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
            $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>IP Address / Subnet Mask</b></font></th>"
            $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$(gwmi -ComputerName $Target Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPEnabled -eq $true } | Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddress } | Foreach-Object { [IPAddress]$_ } | Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'Internetwork' } | Foreach-Object { $_.IPAddressToString }) / $($objAdapter.IPSubnet)</font></td>"
            $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
            $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
            $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
            $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Default Gateway</b></font></th>"
            $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.DefaultIPGateway)</font></td>"
            $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        
        }
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>DHCP enabled</b></font></th>"
        If ($objAdapter.DHCPEnabled -eq "True")
        {
            $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>Yes</font></td>"
        }
        Else
        {
            $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>No</font></td>"
        }
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                            <th width='25%'><b>DNS Servers</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  "                            <td width='75%'>"
        If ($objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder -ne $Null)
        {
            $Report+=  " $($objAdapter.DNSServerSearchOrder) "
        }
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Primary WINS Server</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.WINSPrimaryServer)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $Report+=  "                    <tr>"
        $Report+=  "                        <th width='25%'><b>Secondary WINS Server</b></font></th>"
        $Report+=  "                        <td width='75%'>$($objAdapter.WINSSecondaryServer)</font></td>"
        $Report+=  "                    </tr>"
        $NICCount = $NICCount + 1
        }
    }
$Report+= @"
```

When I run the report, it just returns the same adapter name of "Wi-Fi Ethernet Adapter 4", instead of the actual label of "vLAN1234" or "Backup vLAN" or "Dev vLAN", etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance:

From your second code, **remove** the line `$NICInformation = Get-NetConnectionProfile`

Then, inside the foreach loop get the property you need using:

```
$adapterName = (Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex $objAdapter.InterfaceIndex).Name  # or the .InterfaceAlias if you prefer
```

Also, try to use the newer [`Get-CimInstance` cmdlet instead of `Get-WmiObject`](https://blog.ipswitch.com/get-ciminstance-vs-get-wmiobject-whats-the-difference) and
building the HTML table by concatenating to a string with `+=` is both memory and time consuming.

My recommendation is to build a string **array** using

```
$Report = foreach ($objAdapter in $colAdapters) { .. }
```

and have the code simply output the (sub)strings. Finally, merge everything in the array with

```
$Report -join [environment]::NewLine
```

Then, you are repeating `gwmi -ComputerName $Target Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` where you already have done that and have everything you need already in variable `$objAdapter`..

You can have much cleaner code if you create a [Here-String](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) for each of the adapterinfo parts as a template and insert the values in there. Then again join these with a newline

Comment: Thank you @Theo. I will have to do quite a bit of learning, as what you said is way above my head right now.